# FFMPEG Encoding in Multiple resoultions for adaptive streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding, transcoding

I am using the following ffmpeg script for encoding *mp4 video* into different resolutions for adaptive *HLS/DASH* streaming:

```
 ffmpeg -y -nostdin -loglevel error -i INPUT.mp4 \
    -map 0:v:0  -map 0:v:0 -map 0:v:0  -map 0:v:0  -map 0:v:0  -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a\?:0  \
    -maxrate:v:0 350k -bufsize:v:0 700k -c:v:0 libx264 -filter:v:0 "scale=320:-2"  \
    -maxrate:v:1 1000k -bufsize:v:1 2000k -c:v:1 libx264 -filter:v:1 "scale=640:-2"  \
    -maxrate:v:2 3000k -bufsize:v:2 6000k -c:v:2 libx264 -filter:v:2 "scale=1280:-2" \
    -maxrate:v:3 300k -bufsize:v:3 600k -c:v:3 libvpx-vp9 -filter:v:3 "scale=320:-2"  \
    -maxrate:v:4 1088k -bufsize:v:4 2176k -c:v:4 libvpx-vp9 -filter:v:4 "scale=640:-2"  \
    -maxrate:v:5 1500k -bufsize:v:5 3000k -c:v:5 libvpx-vp9 -filter:v:5 "scale=1280:-2"  \
    -use_timeline 1  -use_template 1 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v  id=1,streams=a" \
    -threads 8 -seg_duration 5 -hls_init_time 1 -hls_time 5 -hls_playlist true -f dash OUTPUT.mpd
```

But the script is giving this error:

> Only '-vf scale=320:640' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters
>   Only '-vf scale=640:1280' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters
>   Only '-af (null)' read, ignoring remaining -af options: Use ',' to separate filters

Please help in resolving the issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `-map 0:a\?:0` -> this should be `-map 0:a:0?` but this is unrelated to the warnings you see. You can ignore those warnings, there's a bug in that code.

Comment: @Gyan, Thanks for the answer. In my output file master.m3u8, there are multiple streams but bandwidth is same for all, is this because of this warning?  

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=131656,RESOLUTION=320x640,CODECS="avc1.64001e,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="group_A1"
media_0.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=131656,RESOLUTION=640x1280,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="group_A1"
media_1.m3u8